# run the different version of php through php-fpm in centos

Tags: php, nginx, centos

I installed PHP 7.2.9 with the source code (name: `php-fpm729`). and installed PHP 5.6.31 (name: `php-fpm`), and set them to listen on different port.

php 5.6.31

path: 
[php 5.6.31 path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SNC3.png)

(/usr/local/php5/etc/php-fpm.conf):
[config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwC44.png)

php7.2.9

path [php 7.2.9 path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzuDc.png)

(/root/php729/etc/php-fpm.conf.default): [php-fpm.conf.default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cjWg.png)

(/root/php729/etc/php-fpm.d/test.conf): [test.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojNvP.png)

nginx: [nginx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVnjn.png)

(/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf):[nginx.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDeki.png)

(/usr/local/nginx/conf/vhost/sea.conf):[sea.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMqy2.png)

I'm sure I've restarted the nginx service and `php-fpm`, but it still show PHP 5.6.31 under `www.sea.com`, I don't know what's wrong, and I've google it still couldn't figure it out,Hope anybody help me...

Here is the img(www.sea.com): **look the last link for reference(link:sea.conf)**

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command to switch between the version or set the default version

```
update-alternatives --config php
```

For more information read this [Multiple PHP version](https://pehapkari.cz/blog/2017/03/27/multiple-php-versions-the-easy-way/)

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?